# If IDs from two different tables are equal, display name from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing a code for my little admin panel, and since I'm not that advanced of a coder, I'm experiencing some troubles with getting a name using two different tables.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
    header("location:main_login.php");
}

include 'db_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE is_dead='0'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<title>Title</title>
<center><img src="header.png"></center>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<? include 'menu.php';?>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Unique ID</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Model</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Last Online</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Options</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td><? if ($rows['unique_id'] == 7815684) { echo '<font color="blue"><b><u>7815684</u></b></font>'; }
elseif ($rows['unique_id'] == 2312964) { echo '<font color="blue"><b><u>2312964</u></b></font>'; }
else { echo $rows['unique_id']; } ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['model']; ?></td>
<td align='center'><font color="green"><b><? echo $rows['last_updated']; ?></b></font></td>
<td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So what I'm trying to do is to get user name, using two tables `$tbl_name` and `$prtalbe` using their unique_id. So, if unique_id from `$tbl_name` equals unique_id from `$prtable`, I want to show user's name from `$prtalbe`.

I've been trying another sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name, $prtable WHERE $tbl_name.unique_id = $prtable.unique_id;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Then doing while loop to get it working

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $rows['name'];
}
```

and it did work actually, but it didn't want to put it right into my code, since `ID` from `$prtable` and `$tbl_name` are different.

Comment: If the IDs are different then these lines will not show up. Your query looks OK and it will definitely *only* request those lines with *equal* IDs. So, where is the problem?

Comment: I just edited to fix several issues, but I am not sure what was intended with the "while loop to get it working" example.  Please check it and correct if I made it worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT $prtable.username FROM $tbl_name INNER JOIN $prtable ON ($tbl_name.unique_id = $prtable.unique_id)";
```

When you call `INNER JOIN` you are fetching all rows from each table and combining them given the `ON` condition. For more information, see this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Okay, I tried doing so and it didn't work for me. Well, I got $rows['name']; but ok, how do I get $rows['id'] and other information> It gives me a blank. Here's a screenshot: http://braxis.ru/JBj.png

And big thank you for your help mate!

Comment: @berdyev Ahh you didn't say you also wanted these other fields as well. Sorry, man; just change `$prtable.username` to `*` in the `SELECT` statement if you want all fields.

Comment: Thank you @gr3co, but there's another problem. $prtable and $tbl_name uses same rows names. So, they have different ID rows in each table. Lets say in $tbl_name user has id = 1, but in $prtable - id = 124. So, how do I display ID from $tbl_name, not from $prtalbe? Thank you! :)

Comment: @berdyev `$rows['$tbl_name.ID']` should do it (instead of `$rows['ID']`)

Comment: Uhhh, the best way to troubleshoot that would be to actually access your database and look at what that query is returning. Copy the query you're sending to your server and run it in your SQL command line prompt at your server and look at what that returns. Then copy the column name you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think I can do that. Or I guess I never tried it and I don't know where is it located. Is there a possible way to get this id, IF:

$prtable.unique_id = $tbl_name.unique_id from $tbl_name? BTW! I updated sql query to:

'$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name INNER JOIN $prtable ON ($tbl_name.unique_id = $prtable.unique_id) WHERE is_dead='0'";'

Since I want to see only alive players (is_dead).

Comment: Wait, so the ID you are trying to return is `$tbl_name.unique_id`?

Comment: No. Here's tables structures. ($prtalbe:http://braxis.ru/MBj.png $tbl_name: http://braxis.ru/LBj.png ), and how can you they have same unique_id's and just id's. But ID's from $tbl_name may differ, since $tbl_name stores dead and alive players. So, what I'm trying to get is, let say Ata's (is_dead=0) ID from $tbl_name.

Comment: Then yeah, you would access that field by calling `$tbl_name.id`.

Comment: I'm doing so and it just won't work :c Is there a possibility we can chat? so I'll be able to show you my code and what esle that needed

Comment: And what if we'll create new sql query like this:

$queryselect = "SELECT $tbl_name.id AS userid FROM $tbl_name, $prtable WHERE $tbl_name.unique_id = $prtable.unique_id WHERE is_dead = '0'";

And make it work thru while loop. Do you think will it work?

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` instead of selecting from multiple tables, then it should work. Also I must get back to work; sorry for not being able to help you all the way.

Comment: No worries, you helped me a lot already :) Last thing, how exactly should I use INNED JOIN? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Upvotes are very much welcome :P and `INNER JOIN` is for when you want to combine two tables and only return rows that contain the common element you specify with the `ON` statement. Read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I'll try, thank you. And about upvotes, it says I need to have 15 reputation, but seems like I dont :/